# How to vectorize code with 3 loops that generates a matrix

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Could you help me to vectorise this Matlav code constructing a matrix `A` of dimension `MNx(2+N-1)xR` in order to speed it up? At the moment it takes approx. 8 sec

INITIALISING

```
R=200;
M=400;
N=20;
B=[kron((1:1:M)', ones(N,1)) repmat((1:1:N)', M,1)]; %(MN)x(2)
```

`B` looks like

```
B=[1 1;
   1 2;
   ...;
   1 20;
   2 1;
   2 2;
   ...
   2 20;
   ...
   400 20]
```

CODE

```
A=[ repmat(B,1,1,R)  zeros(M*N,N-1,R)]; %Allocate the space
                                        %(MN)x(2+N-1)x(R)
                                        % I want A(:,1:2,r)=B for r=1,...,R


%Fill the remaining columns of A in the following way
for r=1:R
    utemp1=randn(M*N, N-1); %Generate a matrix of random 
                            %numbers of dimension (M*N)x(N-1)
    utemp2=randn(M, N);  %Generate a matrix of random 
                         %numbers of dimension (M)x(N)
    utemp3=zeros(M*N,N-1); %Generate a matrix of random 
                           %numbers of dimension(M)x(N-1)
    for m=1:M
        for j=1:N
            utemp3((m-1)*N+j,:)= utemp2(m,j)+[utemp2(m,1:j-1) utemp2(m,j+1:N)]; %(1)x(N-1)
              %e.g. if m=2, j=3, I want to fill the 23th row of utemp3
              %with utemp2(2,3)+[utemp2(2,1:2) utemp2(m,4:20)];

              %e.g. if m=4, j=1, I want to fill the 61st row of utemp3
              %with utemp2(4,1)+[utemp2(4,2:20)];
        end
    end
    A(:,3:end,r)=utemp1+utemp3;     %sum utemp1
end
```

SOME EXPLANATIONS

for `r=1,...,R`

`A` is such that

for `m=1,...,M` and for `j=1,...,N`

the row in `A(:,:,r)` starting with `[m j]` in the first two columns is filled in the remaining `(N-1)` columns with `uj+uh+ujh` for each `h~=j`, where `uj, uh, ujh` are i.i.d standard Gaussian numbers that can be found in `utemp1` and `utemp2`.

Comment: Please also describe the problem that you're trying to solve and not just dump code and ask us to vectorize it... If we know what you're _trying to do_, perhaps we could suggest a built-in or a FEX function...

Comment: ... and after that what do you want to do with A?

Comment: It is part of a very long code (Method of simulated moments estimation). In short, I use it to estimate the parameters of a model using some data. I want to gain some efficiency because I need to repeat that step 500 times.

Comment: If you want to sum elements of each row I think there are some fast built-ins  available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can precompute the indices and use them in 500 iterations:

```
idx = repmat(reshape(1:M*N,M,N).',1,N);
idx = reshape(idx(logical(kron(~eye(N),ones(1,M)))),N-1,[]).';
for k=1:500
    for r=1:R
        utemp2=randn(M*N,1);
        A(:,3:end,r)=randn(M*N, N-1)+bsxfun(@plus,utemp2,utemp2(idx) );
    end
end
```

However allocating large matrices ,specially of repeated elements, and vectorizing operations on it is not always  the most efficient way. There are built-in functions that directly operate on the original array avoiding repeating elements of the array.